# Finding any drive serialno, modelno, type

Tags: drive, serial-number

I'm not able to find the serial number, model number, and type of drives attached to my system programmatically.

So, can anyone help me out of this problem?

Comment: What OS, programming language, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Run...
Type cmd to bring up Command Prompt.

enter

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
wmic csproduct get name
```

Hope this helps.